# Android AIDL problem with activity and service

Tags: android, android-service, aidl

I'm writing an Android 2.1 app which supposed to display a dialog to the user when an external event triggers one of the GPIO's. I have written the Linux device driver, and written the JNI user-space interface to it.
When my app start it launches a remote service which polls the device driver. With aidl, I managed to communicate between the activity and the service, however, when I'm closing the activity, I want the service to relaunch the activity.
I achieved that using the following code: (in the service)

```
Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),WiegandDemoActivity.class);
dialogIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
getApplication().startActivity(dialogIntent);
```

Right after that, I want to communicate using the aidl, so I used:

```
synchronized (listeners) {
for (WiegandListener listener : listeners) {
    try {
         listener.handleWiegandUpdated();
...
```

The activity is brought to front, however the aidl message doesn't reach it.
why is that happening ? (when the activity is in front, everything works fine)

I didn't want to post all the code here because it's big, but if you need more information don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if your RemoteInterface is still bound? Perhaps put some logging in the services's onBind, onRebind and onUnbind methods and see if that sheds any light on the matter. If the sequence ends with an unbind, then you have no interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to re-bind to the remote Activity. Is it practical to have the Activity register to the service when it starts - so the update code is triggered when you *know* that the new Activity is ready to receive incoming messages?

Also be sure to un-register your event listener when your activity closes - otherwise it hangs around. If it contains a reference to the actual activity, then the whole activity remains in memory and doesn't get Garbage collected (even though it's closed and you've created a new one).

Comment: how come using weakHashMap (of the listeners , on the service side) won't work as a precaution of this memory leak ?

Comment: There's no reason it shouldn't, as far as I can see; you would just need to be careful to consider the case that one of them has been garbage collected (I don't know what will happen here, but I imagine it throws an exception that you can sensibly catch, and then remove the listener from your list).

Comment: well , i think it works , but it will only show that there is a problem (null , or return true for isEnqueued) only after a while , and not just as soon as the activity is gone . for example , even if only one activity registers to a listener on the service (and doesn't request to remove the listener) , the hashMap might be larger than 1 . it's probably because of the GC coming later .